# Laravel Request

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to validate some form inputs using laravel request. The name may contain hyphen or dots (for example Mr. Example-of-name). The validation rule alpha cannot take any hyphen or dots. how to do this validation then? and also for the address, user may use comma between Road No, Sector No. etc. For phone number if I use exactly:11. it cannot take phone number with 11 digits. I get error message that the phone should be 11.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'name'           => 'required|max:60',
      'email'          => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
      'password'       => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
      'phone'          => 'required|numeric',
      'address'        => 'required|min:5',
      'profession'     => 'required|min:3',
      'conditions'     => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Use regular expression for this.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-regex

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski I give the suggestion to tawsif. I did not use it

Answer (score 0):

Use **Laravel**'s build-in regular expressions *(regex)* validation rule for this:

[Regular Expressions for Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-regex)